# Проблема с записью картинки в файл

Tags: php, файлы, кодировка, изображения

Проблема заключается в следующем, я получаю из 1С картинку в виде текста, выглядит это как картинка открытая через notepad, записываю её через:

```
$img = fopen('img.jpg', "w+");
fwrite($img, $data);
fclose($img);
```

Проблема заключается в том что у рабочей картинки из 1С в самом начале файла присутствуют символы "яШя", а в полученной картинке их нет. Если их добавить вручную через текстовый редактор, картинка нормально открывается. При попытки дописать их при записи файла, он сохраняет его в кодировке UTF8 без BOM, и тогна вообще ничего не работает, нужно как то дописать эти символы и сохранить в ANSI, или если у вас есть другие способы решения этой задачи, буду рад выслушать.

Comment: Покажите сохраненный файл открытый в шестнадцатеричном редакторе (в тотал командаре например такой режим просмотра есть).

Comment: а куда его можно скинуть?

Comment: Картинку в вопрос можно вставить.

Comment: нужен весь файл в шестнадцатеричном формате или только часть?

Comment: в общем, вот файл который был записан через php: [ссылка](http://prntscr.com/h1p1jp)
А вот это тот же файл, но рабочий, который хранится в 1С: [ссылка](http://prntscr.com/h1p2cd)

Comment: `w+` пробуйте заменить на `wb`.

Comment: к сожалению, без изменений

Comment: `wb` и вместо `$data` записать `chr(0xFF) . chr(0xD8) . chr(0xFF) . $data`

Comment: Отлично, все работает, спасибо большое

Comment: Вам все равно нужно разобраться, куда пропадают первые три байта.

Comment: А чем плохо такое решение?

Comment: Тем, что не ясна причина пропажи. Вдруг ни с того, ни с сего поведение изменится и придет полный файл, а вы к нему все еще будете дописывать три байта.

Comment: Вообще, на будущее, для передачи данных такого формата, лучше всего кодировать данные, например, в `base64`. Источник выдает закодированную в base64 картинку, а потом в файл сохраняем как `base64_decode($data);`
Так мы ничего не потеряем, и все будет на месте.